# Binding two tables and show it in the datagridview C# Winforms SQLite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

Basically I have a datagridview which already has columns.

Everytime that I try to show data in the datagridview, it makes new columns, instead of going into the columns that I already have.

;-;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfuan.jpg)

```
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT members.name, members.number, members.age, members.occupation, jobs.sector FROM members LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs ON members.occupation = jobs.name", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add("members");
        adapter.Fill(ds, "members");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "members";
```

Comment: Have you set the grids `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`? This property defaults to `true`, is not in the designer, and needs to be set in code. And have you set each column’s `DataPropertyName` to point to the column name you want in the table?

Comment: John, can I kiss you? Thank you!!!!!!! Putting DataPropertyName magically solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns=false;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).